# Attaching a image to a pdf using c# and itextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf

i am a new to c# programming and i am doing a project that can capture the screen and attach it to a pdf,in my project i need to attach an screenshot of my desktop or application directly to PDF file, i know how to attached a image that has been saved in to the Hard Drive, in this case i used iTextsharp library. what i need to know is there a way to attach the image directly to PDF without saving the image to Hard Drive. till now I can capture my screen and save it to the hard drive. please direct me to a path, Thanx In Advance , code i used is bellow

this is the code i used to capture the screen

```
string pHotoTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd, HH mm ss");
        Size s = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 90, s);


        System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        stream.Position = 0;
        // later:

        //bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\NiyNLK\Documents\TESTs\" + pHotoTime + ".jpg");
        bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\NiyNLK\Documents\TESTs\MyImage.jpg");
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

below code is used to attached the image
    enter code here

```
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle r = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(400, 400);
        var doc = new Document(r);
        string path = @"c:\users\niynlk\documents\tests";
        string Imagepath = @"C:\Users\NiyNLK\Documents\TESTs";
        try
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(path + "/Images.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Image"));
            Image img = Image.GetInstance(Imagepath + "/MyImage.jpg");
            img.ScalePercent(25f);
            doc.Add(img);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            doc.Close();
        }
```